# Incorrect relative node position in axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw a path in a graph plotted with `pgfplots`, using relative (`++`) coordinates. The following code compiles without any error, but the points are not at the desired position:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
     \addplot{x^2};
     \draw (1,2) --++ (0,1) --++ (1,0) --++ (0,1); % This should result in a staircase
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Any idea of what causes this problem?

Comment: I can't answer the question about the cause of the problem, but you might like to make the staircase with "const plot" instead.  For example, try adding a new line: `\addplot [red,const plot] {x^2};`

Comment: Thank you, but I am not particularly interested in plotting a staircase: this is just an simple example of a path based on relative coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can find in the [PGFPlots manual in 4.17.1 on page 349 (v1.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=349) you need to use `axis direction cs` to make relative coordinates work.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat' level or higher so you don't need to state `axis cs:'
    % at the coordinates
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot{x^2};
            \draw [red,very thick] (1,2)
                -- ++(axis direction cs:0,1)
                -- ++(axis direction cs:1,0)
                -- ++(axis direction cs:0,1)
            ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: For your information: Besides accepting the answer you could also [upvote](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it by clicking on the the 'up' arrow above the answer's score.

Comment: `axis direction cs` or `axis description cs` ??  Your code differs from your description.

Comment: @Thruston, sorry, my fault. Corrected my "typo". Thanks for the hint.