# Mix coordinate systems in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

I try to understand coordinate systems of pgfplots, an MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=\textwidth, height=0.7\textwidth, restrict x to domain = 1:10, xmin=1, xmax=10, clip=false]
\addplot gnuplot[raw gnuplot, color=red, no marks, thick]{set samples 1000; plot x**2*sin(x)};
\filldraw[blue!50] (rel axis cs:-0.1,1.1) rectangle +(axis cs:2,1);
\end{axis}      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Actually I need to draw some graph (function or table with points) and several primitives (lines, rectangles) above of that graph. Because I don't know in advance maximum y-value I use relative coordinates for primitives. But I also need to use `axis cs:` coordinates for x in primitives. Is it possible to mix different coordinate systems: `\draw (a,b) rectangle (c,d)`, where `a` and `c` are in `rel axis cs:`, but `b` and `d` are in `axis cs:`?

And the second question: how to clip primitives to same x limits as for graph? In my MWE rectangle starts at some coordinate (say, x=0) and I want it to be clipped at x=1, as the graph. If I use `clip=true` this will completely erase the rectangle.

Comment: You can access the min/max values of the axis with e.g. `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/how-to-access-xmin-xmax-ymin-ymax-from-within-pgfplots-axis-environment/22021#22021

Comment: I don't really understand your last question. Your entire rectangle is outside the `axis`, so naturally the whole thing disappears with (the default) `clip=true`. Try `\filldraw[blue!50] (rel axis cs:-0.1,1.1) rectangle (axis cs:2,1);`, you'll see that the blue rectangle does appear. (You have `+(axis cs:2,1)` in your code.)

Comment: This is not what I need, sorry, or I don't understand how to use that answer. It is said there that `xmin, ...` etc. should be set explicitly, but I dont know `ymax` before the graph. So, e.g. I need to draw rectangle from (0,70) to (2,75). How can I do this if I don't know "70" -- value depending on `ymax`?

Comment: Oh sorry, that part is a bit outdated, it also works if `xmin` etc. is *not* set explicitly. `\draw (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-5) rectangle (2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});`?

Comment: Concerning my second question. I draw somehow rectangle from (0,70) to (2,75), and graph below. And I want to clip this rectangle to be from (1,70) to (2,75). In other words, initially I have graph and rectngle start from x=0, and then I want to clip both to start from x=1. How to do this?

Comment: Seems to me that `clip=true,xmin=1` would do that, but perhaps I misunderstand what you're saying.

Comment: As already stated in my answer, your question is a bit unclear. Is there any need to draw outside the `axis` rectangle? If not, then Torbjørn is totally right: Just use `clip=true` (or just omit this key, because it is true by default).

Comment: Yes, thanks, `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}` really works! I can use it as `(0, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}*1.1)` etc.

Comment: Yes, I need to draw outside `axis` and clip only in x.  Unfortunately, `clip=true` erases in both coordinates, and I want y direction remain unclipped: clip only width of rectangle, not its height.

Comment: Right, I see. What about having `clip=false,xmin=1` and drawing from `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}` then? (Or, see Stefan's answer.)

Comment: OK, Stefan's approach with `scope` and `clip` works. But another small thing: how to set desired width of rectangle when using `\pgfkeysvalueof`? `\draw (...) rectangle + (2, \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})` gives odd output ...

Comment: For the question in you last comment have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348822.

Comment: Or even better: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358706. (And have a look who has asked that question :))

Comment: Yes, right! I'm so stupid ... how could I forget `axis direction cs:` in my own question. I'm so sorry.

Comment: *g, not a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately your question isn't very precise so I am a bit guessing what you really want. If this isn't what you are asking for, please edit your question accordingly.

Please have a look at the comments of the code for details.

```
% used PGFPlots v.1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat' level or higher so you don't need to prepend
    % TikZ coordinates by `axis cs:' because it is the default coordinate
    % system then
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=1,
        xmax=10,
        % use this key--value only, if you really need to draw something
        % outside the axis limits
        clip=false,
        % just in case you cross the axis border, it should be drawn on top
        % of everything
        axis on top,
    ]
        \addplot gnuplot [
            raw gnuplot,
            color=red,
            no marks,
            thick,
            % there is no need for the 1000 samples, the default is fine
            % when used together with `smooth'
            smooth,
        ]{
            % added plot limits here
            plot [1:10] x**2*sin(x);
        };

        \filldraw [blue!50]
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % here is a way how you can mix different coordinate systems
            ({rel axis cs:-0.05,0} |- {axis cs:0,15})
                rectangle
            % (as written above: when using an appropriate `compat' level
            %  there is no need to write `axis cs:')
            ({rel axis cs:0.3,0} |- {0,35})
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        ;

        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % use a scope and `\clip' to solve problem b
        % (of course you can also use the above shown method of mixing
        %  coordinate systems here, but in addition you can access the axis
        %  limits and use them directly)
        \begin{scope}
            \clip
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
                    rectangle
                (rel axis cs:1,1)
            ;
            \fill [green!50] ({rel axis cs:0.1,0} |- {axis cs:0,-50})
                circle (50pt);
        \end{scope}
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thank you! I can use your method of `scope` and `clip` with some modifications.