# Calculation with ymax in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

To continue my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389194/mix-coordinate-systems-in-pgfplots) now I'd like to understand how to use `ymax`, `ymin` etc. values in new variables made with `pgfmathparse` or `pgfmathsetmacro`. So, if I know `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}` and `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}` how to set new variable `\eh` being `(ymax - ymin)/10`? This code:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\eh}{0.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax} -0.1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}
```

gives the error message: Missing number, treated as zero. I'd like to use this `\eh` as a height of rectangle or in other calculations of coordinates.

**EDIT:**

Added MWE as asked.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true }
   \begin{axis}[
                 xmin=1,
                 xmax=4,
                 grid=both,
                 clip=false
                 ]

        \addplot[thick,red,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}/1.3}] {x^2};
        \draw [black, thick] (1,12.7) -- (2.5,12.7);
        \draw [blue, thick] (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}+0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (4,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}+0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is based on @koleygr answer. In this particular example `ymin=1`, `ymax=10` and they are not set explicitly by user. Hence blue and black lines should have the same y-coordinate, but they are not. And how to simplify input by setting a new variable with all that staff `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}+0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}`?

Ideally I woild like to place objects (lines, rectangles etc.) above the main graph (above `y=10` in this particular example) and the distance these objects are shifted from `ymax` should depend on the size of the main graph, i.e. `y-coordinate-of-objects = ymax + 0.3*(ymax - ymin)`.

Comment: As you can see in my answer I suppose that your problem was that you did not used a \xdef to store \eh... \eh can be seen only from inside your tikzpicture (that is a separate environment) and is lost outside. I add some code to let you keep precision in your calculations and to be able to print outside of the plot area (I can comment my code if needed)

Comment: It sounds like you should just be using `rel axis cs`. I mean, the y-coordinate in your last line there should be the same as that of `rel axis cs:0,1.3`.

Comment: Your MWE works out of the box when using PGFPlots v1.16. Do you agree and if yes, is it ok for you when we close this question as "of-topic" because updating to the recent version solves your problem?

Comment: Yes, I agree, it works now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is solved by updating PGFPlots to the most recent version (1.16).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can use it and many things you have to use and know for something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/number format/precision=1, 
    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill=true }
   \begin{axis}[
                 ymin=1,
                 ymax=10,
                 xmin=1,
                 xmax=4,
                 grid=both,
                 clip=false
                 ]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\eh}{0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax} -0.3*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}}
        \xdef\ehg{\num[round-mode=places, round-precision=1]{\eh}}
        \addplot[thick,red,domain=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}/1.3}] {x^2};
        \draw[-,thick,green] ($(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\eh)$) node[left] (A) {\ehg}
        --($(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\eh)$);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

value of macro=\ehg
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but ... This doesn't work if don't know (and explicitly set) in advance values of `ymin` and `ymax`. Just comment `ymin=1` and `ymax=10` and this leads to the same error message about missing number. I thought these values become known to PGF after `\addplot[...]{x^2}`, and we can extract them somehow.

Comment: Please add a MWE to saw what you want to do. (Of course you have to know the values you want to use...) If you mean to find automatically some values of a tikzpicture it depends on the tikzpicture.

Comment: Please comment (or delete) strings `ymin=1` and `ymax=10` in your answer and this will give an error. Even if we move strings `\pgfmathsetmacro ...` and `\xdef ...` after `\addplot` in your answer this doesn't help also.

Comment: Please add an example of what you want to do... dont care if working or not... Just let as see your picture. Of course it will not work without the values. I don't have to test it.