# Add vertical lines from ymin to ymax

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to add vertical lines to my plot. The problem is that I don't know what `ymax` is, so I cannot just draw them easily. So far I have been able to:

[image: My result]

But I don't know how to shift the top position in a similar way to the bottom.

I can move the top position manually as e.g:

```
\addplot[draw=gray] (16*\i-0.5,0) --                             
                ($ (current axis.above origin)+(15.5,0) $);
```

But it fails when I do it with the variable `\i` as:

```
\addplot[draw=gray] (16*\i-0.5,0) --                             
                ($ (current axis.above origin)+(16*\i-0.5,0) $);
```

I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
                                                  
l.38            \end{axis}
                 
? 
)
Runaway argument?
\def \expandafter \pgfmath@number \expandafter {\the \pgfmath@count }\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfmath@dimen@@.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*>
```

Furthermore, the lines don't go all the way to the top, they only go up until the ticks. How can I make the lines go all the way to the top (or move the ticks to match the lines only in the top)?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                    
\usepackage[top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm,left=2.75cm,right=2.75cm]{geometry}         
\usepackage{tikz}                                                                
\usetikzlibrary{calc}                                                            
\usepackage{pgfplots}                                                            
                                                                                 
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}                                                   
0 10000                                                                          
1 15000                                                                          
2 10000                                                                          
3 20000                                                                          
4 5000                                                                           
5 0                                                                              
\end{filecontents}                                                               
\begin{document}                                                                 
\begin{figure}                                                                   
    \centering                                                                   
    \begin{tikzpicture}                                                          
        \begin{axis} [                                                           
                height = \axisdefaultheight,                                     
                width = \textwidth,                                              
                xlabel = Channel,                                                
                ylabel = Counts,                                                 
                ymin = 0,                                                        
                xmin = -5,                                                       
                xmax = 132,                                                      
                axis on top,                                                     
            ]                                                                    
            % Vertical division of each Board [0-7]                              
            \foreach \i in {0,...,8} {                                           
                \node (a) at (current axis.above origin) {};                     
                \node (b) at ($ (a) + (0-0.5,0) $) {};                           
                                                                                 
                \addplot[draw=gray] (16*\i-0.5,0) -- (b);                        
            }                                                                    
            \addplot[                                                            
                ybar interval,                                                   
                x filter/.code=\pgfmathparse{#1-0.5},                            
                fill = black!20] table {data.txt};                               
        \end{axis}                                                               
    \end{tikzpicture}                                                            
    \caption{Plot.}                                                              
\end{figure}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could do so by combining `axis cs` and `rel axis cs` in one coordinate, similar as I have shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/622134/95441. Thus, I consider this being a duplicate. Nevertheless you could state per comment if this solved your problem. If not, please also let us know in a comment or by editing your question.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I added a bit more detail of what my problem actually is. I can move the top coordinate by hand, but it fails in the loop. I don't understand much of the details, but I think the `axis cs` is not the problem here.

Comment: Use `\path  (current axis.above origin) coordinate (T);                            
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,8}{                                           
                \draw[draw=gray]  (16*#1-0.5,0) -- (16*#1-0.5,0|-T);                     
            }`.

Comment: @ABC That didn't work for me. Lines are not vertical.

Comment: Because you run it in backwards compatibility mode. Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` to the preamble of your document.