# Shouldn't these segment specification be equivalent?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates

According to my understanding of tikz the following two segments, both connecting the origin with the point (-1,0) should be the same.

```
\draw[green, very thick] (0, 0) -- (-1, 0);
\draw[red, very thick]  (0, 0) -- ++(-1, 0);
```

However, the second, instead of going West, it went NorthEast.

[image]

Here is the code that I used on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
                x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, axis lines=middle, 
                ymajorgrids=true, xmajorgrids=true, 
                xmin=-3, xmax=3, ymin=-2, ymax=3,
                xtick={-2,-1,1,2}, ytick={-2,-1,1,2}
        ]
    
            \draw[green, very thick] (0, 0) -- (-1, 0);
            \draw[red, very thick]  (0, 0) -- ++(-1, 0);
    
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348805/incorrect-relative-node-position-in-axis-environment/348822#348822 answers your question.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the true origin (the origin all points are relative to) is the lower-left corner.  Since (-1, 0) is upper-right to the lower-left corner, the end result is next coordinate going up-right-ward.

Comment: In plain Ti*k*Z, those two commands would lead to the exact same output. But you wrote them in an `axis` environment, where relative coordinates have to be set differently. See Torbjørn T.'s link above.